# Javascript execute python file

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, raspberry-pi, sudo

I'm building a house monitor using a Raspberry Pi and midori in kiosk mode. I wrote a python script which reads out some GPIO pins and prints a value. Based on this value I'd like to specify a javascript event. So when for example some sensor senses it's raining I want the browser to immediately update its GUI.
What's the best way to do this? I tried executing the python script in PHP and accessing it over AJAX, but this is too slow.

Comment: _"executing the python script in PHP and accessing it over AJAX [..] is too slow"_ How slow? What is your intended response time?

Comment: It takes about 4-5seconds. I'd like to get it in (almost)real-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by spawning my python script from nodejs and communicating in realtime to my webclient using socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by running my commands through the python c-api, calling py_SimpleString
in javascript, it runs quick.

or

**Take a look at [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), it's probably what you want!**